# Trouble With Pointers C

Tags: c, pointers

I thought I had a somewhat good understanding of pointers but I'm having trouble with my code.  It keeps crashing.

Whenever I try to access stack and pass its contents to b1, my program crashes.

```
int base(int l, int base, int *stack[2000])
{  
    int b1; //find base L levels down
    b1 = base; 

    while (l > 0)
    {
        b1 = *stack[b1 + 1];
        l--;
    } 

    return b1;
}
```

EDIT: the program is a virtual machine assignment that uses a stack architecture. What I'm passing is the current base activation record, and the lexicographical level I'm trying to access. Simply put, they are integers. I'm accessing my stack through a pointer and returning the activation level's base I should be at, but I'm not entirely sure if I'm using pointers correctly.

Comment: Might be helpful to include a description of what the code should do, and maybe what parameters you are passing into it when it crashes.

Comment: @jayjay updated

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: How to use the pointer correctly depends on how the pointer was initialized and what it points to. Since you haven't shown that, we can't really tell you what the problem is.

Comment: After reading b1, put an assert on it against the max size of your stack - 1 (1999).  That will tell you if you are reading out of bounds from bad data to begin with.  Next do you want to pass pointer to an array of 2000 integers, or simpler, just the array itself (which in C is already a pointer and does not pass the entire size of the array by value).  Again, without seeing the calling function or what is passed into "base", we can only take very wild guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you are dereferencing your pointer an extra time, and adding an extra star to the initial declaration as well. If your function accepts an array of integers, as your edit suggests, declare it as

```
int base(int l, int base, int stack[2000])
```

`int *stack[2000]` is an array of pointers to integers, not an array of integers. You then need to change `b1 = *stack[b1 + 1];` to just get an integer out of the array instead of dereferencing a pointer to an integer:

```
b1 = stack[b1 + 1];
```

Finally, you can declare and assign `b1` in the same line:

```
int b1 = base;
```

Really, though, you do not need `b1` at all. Since you are able to decrement `l` based on the fact that C is pass-by-value, you can reassign `base` the same way with no problems.